# How to check if checkbox that is in GridView is checked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have Checkbox and text-box inside a GRIDVIEW.  If checkbox is not checked and the text-box has no comments, then I want to show a message that says please enter comments in the text-box.  I don’t want to show any message if all checkboxes are checked.  I want to accomplish this by using a JavaScript so I have tried but I am not quite there yet and I had some issues all day with this.  Please help.  I am only checking the checkbox here and not the text-box and I am not sure how to check both the checkbox and the text-box so please help.  Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function validate() {
              var flag = true;
              var checkbox = new Array(); 
              var gridview = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
              checkbox = gridview.getElementsByTagName('myCheckbox');
              for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
                  if (checkbox.item(i).checked) 
                  {
                      flag = false;
                      break;
                  }
              }
              if (!flag) {
                  alert('Please enter comments.  Thanks');

              }
              return flag;
          }
</script>
```

and here is my checkbox and the text-box in the aspx file

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Comments">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtComm" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="130px" Height="50px"    BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"
   Text='<%# Eval("COMMENTS")%>'></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15px" HeaderText="Approved?">
       <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="mycheckbox" runat="server"  Checked='<%#Eval("APPR")==DBNull.Value?  false:Eval("APPR") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:
**EDIT :**  Edited to reflect the requested change.

```
function validate() {
    var flag = false;
    var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

    for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++) {
        var inputs = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        var areas = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        if (inputs != null && inputs.length > 1 && inputs[0] != null && areas != null && areas.length > 1 && areas[0] != null) {
            if (areas[1].type == "textarea" && inputs[0].type == "checkbox") {
                var txtval = areas[1].value;
                if (!inputs[0].checked && (txtval == "" || txtval == null)) {

                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    flag = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        alert('Please enter comments.  Thanks');

    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response but i don't see where you are checking if the text-box has any comments.  I want to check if the checkbox is not checked and the textbox is blank then show message.  thanks

Comment: thank you so much, i will test it and let you know soon

Comment: i just tested and am just getting the message every time even if the condition is true or false.  Here is the condition, if the checkbox is checked then i don't need any comments entered in the text-box BUT, if the checkbox is not checked then comments is required.  I am almost there so please help.  thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you have textarea, not textbox. Please check the edited code. It works fine in test.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i have 2 text-boxes and 2 checkboxes how would the code know which one is it checking?  Here is the order of the controls in my gridview:  dropdown   textbox1  textbox2   checkbox1  checkbox2. i want to check textbox2 and checkbox1.  thanks

Comment: it does not work, i am still getting the message and the only time that i don't get the message is when i check all the checkbox and put some comments all the text-box in the gridview.  I should only be getting the message when of the checkbox is not  checked and no comments is provided.  If all checkbox is checked then no message should be showing but if one of the checkbox is not checked then  comments is required for that unchecked checkbox.

Comment: Did you mean !Checkbox.Checked && txtbox.Text ==""? Edited the code. Should work now.

Comment: thank so much for your time and efforts and being so patient with me. i believe this time is working very well.  thank you again.  Jazakalaah bro